# heroku can't find a version of unicorn_binance_websocket_api that satisfies the requirement binance.client

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-api

When deploying a python app to heroku, within the requirements.txt file I have got unicorn_binance_websocket_api, however Heroku can't seem to find a version of unicorn-binance-websocket-api that satisfies the requirement binance.client. Has anyone else encountered this and have any suggestions (it works locally)?

error in Heroku logs:

```
       Collecting unicorn-binance-websocket-api
         Downloading unicorn_binance_websocket_api-1.36.1-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement binance.client (from versions: none)
```

Comment: It sounds like your `requirements.txt` file might be malformed. Any chance you are depending on `unicorn_binance_websocket_api==binance.client` or something? Or are you depending on`binance.client` when you should maybe be depending on `binance`? Please show us your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

unicorn-binance-websocket-api and python-binance use both the websockets library, in your case they require different version of it.

you can replace python-binance with unicorn-binance-rest-api then you dont have the problem anymore.

the migration is very easy:

```
from unicorn_binance_rest_api.manager import BinanceRestApiManager as Client
```

https://www.lucit.tech/unicorn-binance-rest-api.html